# Is it possible to create an unapproved comment using the WordPress XMLRPC API?

Tags: python, wordpress

I'm trying to create a comment, using the [Python library](http://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/wordpress.html#wordpresscomment) for WordPress's XMLRPC API, and set the comment's status to unapproved or "hold". But all comments insertions via the API seem to create approved comments.

```
  comment = WordPressComment()
  comment.content = body
  comment.status = 'hold'
  wp.call(NewComment(post_id, comment))
```

Is this parameter not supported on the create comments method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer: it's not directly possible by setting the status on the NewComment request.

But you can use the `pre_comment_approved` filter to define your own handler and add an unapproved status when the comment is inserted into the database.

Comment: It's also possible to [create custom methods](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25507463/1287812) and retrieve/set granular information.